# $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

I know, it looks very similar to other question like this but this one is little different because of boundaries since it is involved complete $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Question is to show that: if $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=0$$ than is $$f=0$$ almost everywhere.

What should one do in such case because in other question boundary of integration is a specific space?

Comment: hint: use Riemann Sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f$ is not $0$ almost everywhere. This means that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in A$ where $A$ is a set of positive measure.

Now you can write
$$
A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n\,,
$$
where $A_n = \{ x \in A: f(x) > n^{-1}\}$. Because $A$ has positive measure, some of the sets $A_n$ have positive measure, say $m(A_k) > 0$, and thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx \geq \int_{A_k} f(x) \, dx \geq m(A_k) \frac{1}{k} > 0\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : for every $c>0$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t) dt = \int_{ \{f \geqslant c\}}f(t)dt + \int_{\{f<c\}} f(t)dt $$

On the RHS, the first term is greater than $c\lambda(f \geqslant c)$.